# Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system

I am having trouble installing Ubuntu at the moment. When I press F12 (my lap is Dell), I pressed the command install Ubuntu then my lap stop working, it freezes, both the mouse and the touchpad. How can I fix that, thank you!!

Comment: Please provide some more information on the installation medium and type of laptop. And also, have you tried to boot in the live environment? does that work correctly, if so, you might try installing from there.

Comment: "

Please provide some more information on the installation medium and type of laptop.

And also, have you tried to boot in the live environment? does that work correctly, if so, you might try installing from there.
"